# How to save executable files for C code in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When I create new files in VS Code for Mac and write C code there, some of them are saved together with **.o** file and **exec** file. Others just with document type files without extension.
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXM9i.png)

Could you tell me please how to correctly save a file with C code so that it is included all necessary files to be transferred and executed on another computer.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "on another computer" you mean another Mac, right? Otherwise it's not possible.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, why some .c files with code are saved with document type file and another with .o file and exec file? What files I need to attach to the main file with code with .c extension if I want to transfer it to windows computer and to another Mac?

Comment: File ending in `.c` Are typically C source files. File ending in `.o` are typically *object* files, usually created from C source files. The object files are then *linked* to form the final executable program file.

Comment: And C code is compiled to match a specific target (Mac, Windows, etc.) and are not portable between different targets (without special emulation layers). So a program compiler for Windows can't run on macOS. And a program compiled for macOS can't run on Windows.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, thanks for explanation! Do you know what should I do when I to save `.c` file so that the `.o` and `exec` files are generated as well?